# How to exclude a value from VLOOKUP and MAX if checkbox is checked?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am using the following formula to pull in values based on the `MAX` found in a range and it is working perfectly. I would now like to find a way to exclude a value if the checkbox in that row is checked.

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(MAX('3B Proj.'!$F$2:$F$47),{'3B Proj.'!$F$2:$F$47,'3B Proj.'!$A$2:$A$47},2,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Since your key is in column F your checkbox column must be on the right, so for example, if the checkboxes are in column G you can multiply column F with the inverse of the checkbox value and get the maximum.

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(MAX(NOT('3B Proj.'!$G$2:$G$47)*'3B Proj.'!$F$2:$F$47),{'3B Proj.'!$F$2:$F$47,'3B Proj.'!$A$2:$A$47},2,0))
```

**Sample Output in a simplified spreadsheet:**

[image]

Comment: If I answered your question, please click the accept button. By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved. If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Now that I have that portion working I am wanting to apply the same to two more columns that have numeric values in them but when I add the same formula NOT('3B Proj.'!$A$2:$A$47)* it changes the numeric value. I'm basically wanting whichever name pulled over from the VLOOKUP the corresponding columns to the left of it show up as well